# User Defined object inside list not iterated properly

Tags: java, jdbc

In this example code I am getting two records from database then that data I have set to `smsDTO` object that I had put `ArrayList`. if i iterate this `ArrayList` in another class that last record printing twice instead of first record.

**Database class**

```
 public ArrayList<SmsDTO> getReulst() {
                ResultSet rs = null;
                Connection conn = null;
                PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
                ArrayList<SmsDTO> ar=new ArrayList<SmsDTO>() ;
                SmsDTO sms = new SmsDTO();
                try {

                    conn = getConnection();
                    String query = "select pt.P_MOBILE,st.S_FIRSTNAME,st.REF_ID  from parent_info pt join student_info st on pt.REF_ID = st.REF_ID  where st.S_CLASS_TO_JOIN = 10;";

                    pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query); // create a statement
                    rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
                    // extract data from the ResultSet
                    while (rs.next()) {

                        long phone = rs.getLong(1);
                        sms.setPhone(phone);
                        String student_name = rs.getString(2);
                        sms.setStudentname(student_name);
                        String ref = rs.getString(3);
                        sms.setRef(ref);
                        ar.add(sms);

                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    try {
                        rs.close();
                        pstmt.close();
                        conn.close();
                    } catch (SQLException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                return ar;
            }
        }
```

**Another class**

```
method()
{
    ArrayList<SmsDTO> lhst = null;
    try {
        lhst = db.getReulst();
        for (Iterator iterator = lhst.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            SmsDTO smsDTO = (SmsDTO) iterator.next();
            System.out.println(smsDTO.getStudentname());
        }
}
```

Comment: It´s not that it does loop wrong, you simply just add the one instance of  `SmsDTO `over and over again (`sms` is never reassigned) and modify this instance in the  meantime. So you are left with `x` times the same instance of `SmsDTO` in the `List`, where this one instances has the data of the last iterated database row.

Answer (score 0):

```
public ArrayList<SmsDTO> getReulst() {
        ResultSet rs = null;
        Connection conn = null;
        PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
        ArrayList<SmsDTO> ar = new ArrayList<SmsDTO>();
        SmsDTO sms = null;
        try {

            conn = getConnection();
            String query = "select pt.P_MOBILE,st.S_FIRSTNAME,st.REF_ID  from parent_info pt join student_info st on pt.REF_ID = st.REF_ID  where st.S_CLASS_TO_JOIN = 10;";

            pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query); // create a statement
            rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
            // extract data from the ResultSet
            while (rs.next()) {
                sms = new SmsDTO();
                long phone = rs.getLong(1);
                sms.setPhone(phone);
                String student_name = rs.getString(2);
                sms.setStudentname(student_name);
                String ref = rs.getString(3);
                sms.setRef(ref);
                ar.add(sms);

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                rs.close();
                pstmt.close();
                conn.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return ar;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create `SmsDTO sms = new SmsDTO();`  inside while loop

You are inserting same object twice into array list. So last updated values will be there in same object(because its same reference).

When you create new object in while loop first record will go to first object and second record will go to newly created second object. (not for the same object).

Comment: if i use hibernate automatically it gives List then no problem right

Comment: yes .You are correct. if you think of Spring Spring-data-jpa is good option